# Prevent duplication of fields in child class

Tags: typescript

```
class Parent {
    // how can we decorate this field to 
    // prevent duplication in the child?
    readonly name: string; 
}

class Child extends Parent {
    readonly name: string;
}
```

That is the kind of scenario I would like to cause a compiler error.

### Edit

This is the scenario that occurs when running the code with babel-jest.

```
class Parent {
  readonly name: string; 
  constructor() { 
    this.name = 'foo';
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  readonly name: string;
  constructor() { 
    super();
  }
}

const child = new Child();
document.writeln(child.name); // undefined
```

Comment: Why would you want this behavior?

Comment: I was running into trouble, when compiling with Babel, in which the child class's `name` property was undefined, even though the parent class had set its value. @NurbolAlpysbayev

Comment: @ShaunLuttin can you create an example case?

Comment: I can give it shot... we need an online TypeScript/Babel repl.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such solution (and shouldn't be?), probably because it contradicts with OOP principles like [open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle).

There is a workaround, though (with trade-offs as always).

Make a property private

```
class Parent {
    private name: string = '';
}
```

this way the property in child class would cause compilation error "Types have separate declarations of a private property"

Comment: Nice concept, but aren't child classes inherently modifications of their parents?

Comment: It's kind of philosophical, but what I was trying to get at is that the notion of child class that doesn't modify its parent is nonexistent. The existence of a child class is a modification of a parent class. But hey, I'm here to learn. School me

Comment: Your american english is a bit hard for me, but if I got you correctly, you are generally correct, child should always be able to extend, i.e. modify properties of properties (makes sense?) of parent class. However, I am no good teacher for this subject, I ain't got even CS degree. So you should read the wikipedia article instead ;) I am more like a practice-guy

Comment: Haha ok. I mean I get the concept I just think it's a bit of Baloney. If I knew the equivalent of Baloney I would try to find it in your language :)

Comment: It's Cheh-pooh-khuh in russian :) I must say many theoretical principles are Baloney in some real world cases.